# Injecting HTML using Chrome extension fails non-deterministically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension to inject HTML before the first result of a Google search  using a content script, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.g:first').before('<div>Hello world!</div>'); 
});
```

The element appears to be inserted correctly into the DOM (querying `$('.g:first')` after insertion gives the new element).  However, the element fails to render about half the time.  This problem occurs regardless of the `run_at` property for content scripts in the extension's manifest.

(Also, very infrequently, `$('.g:first')` does not even return anything because the page has not finished loading in `$(document).ready` - some of the internal HTML elements are not populated.  Not sure if this is related.)

Is this an extension-specific issue?  How can it be resolved?  Debugging suggestions are also welcome!

Comment: @abraham Yes, it is.  Thanks!  I solved the problem with a `MutationObserver` since `DOMNodeInserted`, which was suggested in the accepted answer to that question, is deprecated.